# Using Write or WriteLiteral to write HTML code of a WebPageBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I use the WriteLiteral() method in a class derived from WebPageBase to produce some html output for a section. Everything works fine except, that the HTML code is printed as normal text and not interpreted as HTML tags. How can I write HTML code using the write/writeliteral methods of a WebPageBase?

Here some example code. I want the word "User" to be bold:

```
this.DefineSection("UserInfo", () =>
            {
                string username = "xyz";
                this.WriteLiteral("<b>User:</b> " + username));
            });
```

Comment: Could you show some code to put your question into context?

Comment: What does this output to the resulting HTML exactly? How does it differ from what you expect? When I tested this code it outputted exactly `<b>User:</b> xyz` in the final markup (view page source in the browser) and obviously the word `User:` was shown in bold.

Comment: My page source looks like this: &lt;b&gt;User:&lt;/b&gt; and the output in the browser: <b>User:</b>.

Comment: Ok I got it: I rendered the Section into a var. And the output must be printed via Html.Raw(renderedSection).

Comment: Can you please post the code that worked? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was:

I rendered the Section into a var. And the output must be printed via Html.Raw(renderedSection).

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the MSDN topic for this method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpageexecutingbase.writeliteral(v=vs.99).aspx
"... Writes the specified object **without HTML encoding**."
Can you use another method ... like simply "Write(Object)"?